# Forwarding the port for the redis dashboard in Docker

Tags: docker, web-scraping, redis

I'm working on a new scraping project. I already set up redis inside docker by running this

```
docker run -d --rm --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis:alpine
```

And then I installed redis client and I've successfully gotten redis to run.

[image]

In order to run scrapers locally I need to forward the port for the redis dashboard. I did run this command

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
```

but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Also When I type 127.0.0.1:6379 in browser,The page displaying this
[image]

I did search online and didn't get enough helpful resources for windows platform . Does anyone know how to fix this problem? A guidance would be much appreciated !

Comment: AFAIK, Redis doesn't contain a web server, so you can't interact with it using a browser. You could run something like Redis Commander to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `-p 6379:6379`, docker would bind port 6379 of redis container on  port 6379 of your host. means that you can connect to this redis via port 6379 even out of localhost, for example in network ...

In this case, command `redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379` would be right, and also you can use your network ip instead of localhost ip

If you don't want to connect to this redis over network, it possible not to bind ports, and connect to redis container via its ip, means that use `docker run -d --rm --name redis redis:alpine`, then try to connect with `redis-cli -h CONTAINER_IP -p 6379`. you can find container ip with `docker inspect redis`

Note that browser tries to make connection over http, and won't response any for things like this

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address doesn't work in most common situations and I wouldn't look it up or use it.  You can `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379` to make the container only accessible from the local machine (when `localhost` is the physical host system).